# Exporting String PPI network to Cytoscape

Tags: string, cytoscape

How to export String PPI network to Cytoscape?

Previously, I used to export my PPI network from string database to Cytoscape directly by using "send network to Cytoscape" option in string database. But now I am not able find that option is string. How to rectify this issue to export my String data to Cytoscape?

Answer (score 0):

From Exports options in STRING, you can download the TSV file and then import it to Cytoscape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could install the stringApp and query for your network directly from Cytoscape, along with a number of additional features.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Can use the TSV workaround for now, but am concerned this may herald a broader problem since I'm also having new issues with attempting to connect to STRING in R -  "Failed to execute: http://127.0.0.1:1234/v1/commands/string/protein%20query?query=&cutoff=0.7&limit=0&species=Homo%20sapiens
Error: Failed: Cannot connect to String"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).